# WiFi icon stays orange when using proxy

Tags: wi-fi, proxy

I recently setup a proxy within my home. All my machines and devices (PC and android)can connect to the internet through the proxy. I'm using my tablet now to do so.

The one issue I've seen is that the WiFi icon stays orange (I'm on kitkat, so it would be the same as white people on an earlier version). This seems to affect other apps that asks the OS if there is a connection before even trying.

Is there any documentation around using a proxy that could explain this? Is it a known issue? Is it likely I miss configured something?

Comment: What device is this on? Android version?

Comment: This is on a second gen nexus 7 running 4.4.2. It also happens on my galaxy nexus running 4.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

This was my mistake. I had the proxy server configured incorrectly. Packet forwarding was not turned on so no traffic other than the intercepted port 80 and 443 traffic could reach the internet. Since Google uses ports in the 5000s to determine connectivity and those ports were essentially blocked no internet connectivity could be determined.